# “Puff words”: What is a good definition or explanation for this term by David Foster Wallace?

Tags: meaning, writing-style, formality

The late David Foster Wallace at least once used the term “puff words” to describe, I assume, the type of words in the list below that are not in parentheses. What exactly did Wallace mean by “puff words”?

**Puff word (non-puff word)**

utilize (use)

commence (start)

prior to (before)

therefore (so)

however (but)

Comment: They are of course quite sesquipedalian in nature.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I thought puff words are those which build up the person, place, or thing whom/which they describe. In other words, they almost make the person, place, or thing seem better than it really is. To puff up a presidential candidate in a newspaper column, for example, would involve praising the candidate's accomplishments and giving reasons why s/he would make a good  president. From the Free Dictionary:  (Journalism & Publishing) a flattering newspaper or magazine article about a person or an organization. Puff words would then be flattering words.

Comment: _Puff_ in this situation seems to have a lot in common with _inflated_, or in other words _puffed up_.

Comment: Endeavor to avoid utilizing extended multisyllabic vocabulary at opportunities where monosyllabic core vocabulary suffices.

Comment: *puffed-up* - 1. feeling self-important; arrogant; pompous. 2. swollen; puffy (Dictionary.com)

Comment: Note that the term *puffery* has been around since at least 1820.  Granted, the sense of the word, as defined by most dictionaries, isn't dead-on to *puff word*, but the basic sense is there.  What's perhaps unique to DFW is the description of relatively mundane words using that term, simply because they're not the most concise options, vs tagging only phrases which exploit embellished pronouncements.

Answer (score 7):

We can use DFW's [description](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2015/07/reflections-on-language-david-foster-wallace/), "pretentious, deadening".  They are words that add nothing but dead weight to prose while they inflate the seriousness of that prose (and the author).